# class of expr and exprs are different in rlang in R ! Why?

Tags: r, rlang, nse, quasiquotes

I am not sure if this has been asked here, But I am very confused here. I am reading this awesome book called Advanced R by Hadley Wickham from [here](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html).

There is function called `cement` that has been described here, I have modified it little bit and trying to understand it.

```
library(rlang)
cement1 <- function(x) {
  dots <- expr(x)
  print(class(dots))
  #paste(expr_name(x))
}

cement2 <- function(y,z) {
  dots <- exprs(y,z)
  print(class(dots))
  #paste(purrr::map(dots, expr_name), collapse = " ")
}
```

Running the above `cement1` without any parameter returns me the class of dots as "name".

However, when I run the `cement2` function with additional parameter, the class returns "list", {simply putting class(expr(x)) returns "name" whereas class(exprs(x)) returns "list"}.

I am not getting my head around this as why it is printing different class returned by `expr` and `exprs`. The only difference I thought I knew about them was, one deals with one parameter, other one deals with multiple parameters, but I may be wrong, I might have missed some details.

**Original Problem**: So, it all started by running these two functions separately by removing the comments section in the code for both `cement1` and `cement2`, when I run the functions Below are the output returned by them:

```
cement1(Hello) #Returns , Error in type_of(.x) : object 'Hello' not found 
cement2(Hello) #Works very well and returns, [1] "y z"
```

So I tried to find the reason why `cement1` failed and then printed their classes and that is when I realized , `expr` and `exprs` return different classes.

**My question is**:

1) Are they by design, if yes then why? Or, I am doing some horrible mistake, which I am  currently unable to see.

2) Does `cement1` can't work this if not , what is the correct way?

I am sorry for too long sentences, My first language is not English, hence If anything silly is there, Please let me know I shall correct it. I hope this is not a duplicate, I tried to find the answer but could not found by my own.

Thanks for any help.

**R Version**: 3.4.2
**rlang**: 0.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes, the return values of `expr` and `exprs` differ by design. From the `?expr` help page:

> enexpr() and expr() capture a single raw expression.
>
> enexprs() and exprs() capture a list of raw expressions including expressions contained in `...`.

2) `expr_name()` expects a quoted expression, such as what's produced by `expr()`. So, you need to modify your `cement1` to call `expr_name()` on `dots`, not `x`. You can also remove `paste` because you are not concatenating anything.

```
cement1 <- function(x) {
  dots <- expr(x)
  # print(class(dots))      ## Commented out for clarity
  expr_name(dots)           ## The input to expr_name is now effectively expr(x)
}
cement1( Hello )
# "x"
```

Your function `cement2` basically calls `expr_name()` on every element of the list returned by `exprs()`, then concatenates the results into a single string.

2a) Now that we got your `cement1` working, we can improve it further. Currently, the function doesn't make any use of its input argument `x`. `expr()` simply captures the unevaluated expression, and this expression will always be `x`, regardless of what you name your argument:

```
cement1.1 <- function( completelyIgnoredName ) {
  dots <- expr(x)
  expr_name(dots)
}
cement1.1( Hello )
# "x"
```

However, if you replace `expr()` with `enexpr()`, the function will *substitute* the expression provided as the function's argument and capture *that* instead:

```
cement1.2 <- function(x) {
  dots <- enexpr(x)
  expr_name(dots)
}
cement1.2( Hello )
# "Hello"
```